# Ordering a bar chart with duplicate values?

Tags: excel, sorting, bar-chart, vlookup, index-match

I have data I am trying to visualize on a regular cadence. The data looks something like this:

- SectionA - 2000
- SectionB - 600
- SectionC - 1300
- SectionD - 600
- SectionE - 400

An issue I already solved for is the sections being dynamic-ish. While SectionA is top this month, the next it may be last. I solved for that problem like this:

- Rank - Section - Value
- 1 - indexmatch based on value - value pulled in with large function

The issue with this method is duplicate values. In the example above, B & D have the same value, so when I indexmatch based on the name, it just pulls in the first one found for both of them (SectionB).

How can I remedy this? Is there a way to get indexmatch to skip a value it’s already provided?

Not sure if the way I did it is the best either, there may be a completely different way to solve it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.